# Powershell: run Cleanmgr at system shutdown

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a PS script that is executed at system shutdown (script runs ok and configured properly in gpedit to run at shutdown).

However, after adding this line:

`Start-Process -FilePath CleanMgr.exe -ArgumentList '/sagerun:20' -Wait -Windowstyle Hidden`

the script execution fails - Windows is starting the process and waiting.

Running Cleanmgr with /sagerun parameter doesn't require user input. However, it displays a window with disk cleaning progress - and this may be the issue, as the script is launched at shutdown, in non-interactive mode.

Is there any option to run this process corretly at system shutdown?

Comment: The parameter `/VERYLOWDISK` says it runs without user input and may go better? What did you define as n 20? The local system "user" doesn't really have its own profile, so settings like "Temporary Internet Files" could cause it to complain. You can try setting up a task scheduler task to run it as SYSTEM, so you can test without actually shutting down

Comment: @Cpt.Whale  /verylowdisk doesn't do complex cleanup that I'm looking for. In sageset 20 I turned on all available options. I'll investigate your suggestion on Temp Internet Files etc. - this may be an issue. Thanks.